# Rails Application Controller for critique (feel free to be harsh)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding, controllers

I've written an application controller that handles 99% of what I need any controller to do.  I've posted it [here](http://pastebin.com/f61c0afbf) (pastebin).  Like I said, feel free to be harsh.

-update: added comments :)

Thx,

-C

P.S.  I would like to say that my intention here is to overwrite methods that need different functionality in sub-classed controllers, such as the *_message methods and the after_* methods.  The application controller will serve as a sort of abstract class. also, some of the before_filters are specific to plugins, such as tiny_mce and restful_authentication (which is awesome, imho.)

Comment: This is an interesting approach, and it would be great if you could answer your own question once you have more experience with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer to your question, but if you want to go further in this direction, you may want to take a look at [Hobo](http://hobocentral.net/). Its [Hobo::ModelController](http://github.com/tablatom/hobo/blob/master/hobo/lib/hobo/model_controller.rb) does a lot of what your ApplicationController does.

Answer (score 0):

Small thing, but I would make the object, model, and model_name methods private or protected. Other than that I didn't notice any mistakes.